# Aws S3: How to add subdomain to a static website hosted on s3

Tags: amazon-s3, dns, subdomain, aws-api-gateway, cloudflare

I bought a domain (xyz.com) from some domain provider.

I pointed its nameserver to Cloudflare to host dns.

I created an S3 bucket with name (xyz.com) and hosted my static website on it.

I added a CNAME record on cloudflare to point to the static website url of bucket.

Everything is working fine till here. (xyz.com) opens the static website hosted on S3 bucket.

Now I want to create (api.xyz.com) for AWS API Gateway custom domain.
I want API Gateway to trigger Lambda so that it computes and return back the result.

For above I added another CNAME record in cloudflare so that AWS ACM is able to issue me a certificate for (api.xyz.com). After few minutes ACM was able to issue me a certificate.

Now I added the custom domain in API Gateway and selected the above ACM certificate.

When I make http GET call to my api chrome shows:
This site can’t be reached
api.xyz.com’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

How to fix this?

I am a beginner and maybe I am using some terms wrong. Please Ignore

Comment: Which specific part is causing you difficulties. Did you create the subdomain in your DNS manager (Cloudflare)? Did you create a CNAME record pointing to the API Gateway domain name? What did you try? What was the result?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I edited the question for better understanding. Does above edit answer all your questions? I have done nothing on AWS CloudFront

Comment: Did you create a CNAME record for `api.xyz.com` to point to the API Gateway domain name (eg `api-id.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com`)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No. But after your above comment, I added the CNAME record in the cloudflare. Now when I make API call from postman and when I try to go through browser it shows:

403
Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

Comment: I wonder if this might help: [Setting up custom domain names for REST APIs - Amazon API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a CNAME record to your api gateway and make sure you hit it using https